# Spider plant getting brown. Too cold or over-watering?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants

This spider plant was doing really fine until winter struck. Now the plant was outside in y balcony, was kept away from cold drafts. I was really careful with the watering and watered after the soil was dry 2 inches deep with an interval of a day.

But in winter, I watered the plant and soon it shed 3-4 stalks. They turned brown. Now there are other leaves going brown around the bend.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: Now only 2-3 stalks are remaining and seems like they are also getting brown. The sol drains well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the winter, I water my spider plant maybe once a month. It's in a cool location (60 degrees F, so something like 17-18C) with only diffuse light, and has a ton of little spiders hanging from it. Generally, half of the spiders die each winter, which is expected behaviour. Right now, it's even blooming. I suspect that you're watering it WAY too much. Mine is the species and all green, which makes it somewhat easier to care for because the leaves turn color when they're water-stressed (they get kind of bluish-green/grayish). This is a cue for me to water. When I repotted it last year, I watered it only once (to "set" the potting soil), then ignored it for a month. It was just fine.

Comment: But why the plant developed brown spot over the bend and not the tips first?

Comment: My take on why the damage occurred first on the bends in the leaves has to do with injury to the leave - the bend represented a weak spot or break in the leaf structure, which is why it browned before the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Chlorophytum has very thick, fleshy roots where it stores water to supply to the leaves. The problem is that as the plant ages and the roots accumulate, they start to push the soil out of the pot. Watering wets the roots, but flushes more and more soil out of the pot until there is hardly any soil left - the pot is mostly full of roots. At this point watering just goes in the top, right past the roots and straight out the drainage holes at the bottom.

If this happens and you have no soil to act as a reservoir buffer supply of moisture and nutrient the plant has to steal from the old leaves to make new leaves. Hence you see dying patches on old leaves.

Turn the plant out of the pot and check to see how much root there is compared to soil. If there is lots of soil, maybe all you need is to raise the fertilizer availability a little. If no soil, transplant to a larger pot and give it more soil.

Comment: I re-poted this plant a week or so ago and there is plenty of soil compared to the roots (50:50). This spider plant is driving me crazy. It's my second spider plant, and it is dying for some reason. I used a mixture of Loamy soil + Pumice + vermicompost.

Comment: I checked with the plant now and even the new tips are getting brown.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like too much water while it was dormant.

to find out if its too much water you need
 to check the roots for root rot.

spider plants need intervals between watering times and in winter it should be around 3 weeks depending on humidity and temperatures 
this plant  should be slightly root bound before repotting.

the roots hold large amounts of water so if you repot and water it might be too much water.

check the roots again as you have nothing to lose.

as  a last ditch attempt cut off the rotten roots and put the plant in water 
until the roots develop a bit more before repotting again

good luck hope they make it

Comment: Yes, I watered it after re-potting. I always water plants when re-potting. Is that bad?

Comment: no you should water after re-potting to give the roots good contact with the medium. it's just that spider plant roots hold a lot of water in the roots so if you water it when they are full ...